# CURL batch doesn't do anything - infinite loop

Tags: batch-file, curl

Hi guys i'am new working with curl, I've already played with wget but never with curl.
My problem is i want to download a csv from a url with GET params but when i do the request curl goes to infinite loop and doesn't do anything and doesn't give any error.

```
curl --verbose -X 136.17.0.23:83 -U myProxyUser:myProxyPassword -u myHttpUser:myHttpPassword -o C:\outfile "http://136.16.120.13/webtrac/universal_ajax.aspx?tableIdx=54&mode=export&filters=%%22groupOp%%22:%%22AND%%22,%%22rules%%22:\\[{%%22fnield%%22:%%22Year%%22,%%22op%%22:%%22bw%%22,%%22data%%22:%%222014%%22}\\]}&selection="
```

[image: PRTS]

Comment: Is your batch file called `curl.cmd` or `curl.bat`?

Comment: What you have is a batch file calling itself. Change code inside `curl.bat` to call `curl.exe` (if it is in the path) or include the full path to the executable.

Comment: And (i forget it, sorry) of course, you can change the name to your batch file ;)

Comment: thanks @MCND that's exactly my issue :-)